# JQuery function to show element dependent on the value of hidden HTML input element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Just to preface my answer, I'm an absolute novice when it comes to JQUERY.

I'm trying to create a DOM ready function which takes the value of a hidden HTML input field and if the value is ... (something) then show a certain `<div>` class.

Here's my code:

**JS** - UPDATED

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

    var money = 19.95;

    /* not sure if this is written correctly, but this is supposed to
    check whether the hidden input element value is equal to var money */

   if ($("input[id='VAT_shipping'][type='hidden']").val() == money )  {

    $("#ac-wrapper").show(); 
    $("#popup").show();

    };

    // hide popup when user clicks on close button
    $(".close-btn").click(function(){
        $("#ac-wrapper").hide();
         // hide 
    });

    // hides the popup if user clicks anywhere outside the container
    $("#ac-wrapper").click(function(){
        $("#popup").hide();
    })

    // prevents the overlay from closing if user clicks inside the popup overlay
    $("#ac-wrapper.").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();         
    var $this = $(this);
    var horizontalPadding = 30;
    var verticalPadding = 30;     
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" id="VAT_shipping" value="<? print $shipping; ?>" />

<div id="ac-wrapper">
    <div id="popup">
      <center>
        <p>
       <strong> You have selected World Free Tax Zone - £19.95 for shipping. </strong>

        We will automatically remove the VAT - 20% from your order.

        Please click close to return to review your order.

        </p>
        <button class="close-btn">Close</button>
      </center>
    </div>
      </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#ac-wrapper {
    display:none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.6);
    z-index: 1001;
    }
#popup {

    width: 555px;
    height: 375px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 5px solid #000;
    border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    -moz-box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    position: relative;
    top: 200px; left: 375px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
    text-align: center
}

    .close-btn {
        cursor: pointer;
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #AC9E33;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000000;
    font: bold 11px Sans-Serif;
    text-transform:none;
    padding: 7px 12px;
    margin:0;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.3s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.3s;
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
}
    .close-btn:hover {
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #515280;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000000;
    font: bold 11px Sans-Serif;
    text-transform:none;
    padding: 7px 12px;
    margin:0;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.3s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.3s;
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
}
```

So the jQuery function checks the value of the `shipping` input field and if it is equal to `var money = 19.95` then the `ac-wrapper` and nested `popup` is shown. The client can then close this window, using the `close-btn' or by clicking outside of the element.

Can somebody explain how to do this please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is

```
if ($("input[name='shipping']").val(money); )  {
```

should be

```
if ($("input[id='shipping']").val() == money )  {
```

OR

```
    if ($("input[id='shipping'][type='hidden']").val() == money )  {
```

Comment: 2 problem . On Jquery you are searhcing for classnames `.` but on HTML have id names `#`

Comment: Thanks Amit - I had to change a few things on the CSS but you're `if statement` has worked.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of things you're trying to determine whether or not to show a pop-up based on the value of a drop-down (says in your code). For that you'd need a dropdown.

```
<select id="shipping_dropdown" name="shipping_dropdown" required>
    <option value="">Select shipping method</option>
    <option value="25.00">Not this one</option>
    <option value="19.95">This one</option>
</select>
```

Next you say that you want to read the value from a hidden `<input>` field. Why? This seems unnecessary. You could do the following to read a users' selection.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function({
        $("#shipping_dropdown").change(function(){
            //Handler for when the value of this ID (shippping_dropdown) changes
            if( $(this).val() == "19.95" ){
                //Replace alert() with your pop-up
                alert("You have selected World Free Tax Zone - £19.95 for shipping."); 
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

See about the .change() function [here](http://api.jquery.com/change/).

Comment: Sorry to confuse the issue - that comment was taken from a previous function that I modified. I've removed the comment now - no drop-down menu is involved in this function.

Comment: Ok, so what is the value of the hidden `<input>` based on? Numeric input? Radio buttons? Otherwise there wouldn't be any value in having a hidden input field. If you just need to select the value of a hidden field you can use Amit's answer using `$("#shipping").val() == money` to see if a value is equal to. If the value of the `<input>` changes you need to elaborate your question more. (Nvm: just saw the `print $shipping`), Amit's answer answer's the question)

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
if ($("input[name='shipping']").val(money); )  {
        //code

    $('.ac-wrapper').show().css({'height' : docHeight}); 
    $('.popup').css({'top': scrollTop+20+'px'});
});
```

two syntax error

- first line: `if ($("input[id='shipping']").val()==money )  {`
- last line: `}`

Comment: `;` is also not required for `if`. it should be just like

`if(condition){//code}`